# How to pass correlation ID on OnRemoteFailure property

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm trying to fix an existing code where I will have to include a correlation ID to track the errors. I have used OnRemoteFailure property to handle the "Access Denied" error. It would be great if anyone can help on how to pass a correlation ID to this.
Code:

```
   OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                {

                    // Redirect to an unauthorized page
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    _logger.LogWarning("Remote failure with message {Response}", context.Failure.Message);
                    context.Response.Redirect($"/Account/AccessDenied?e=RemoteFailure");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you store correlationId in Request.Headers ( or maybe in Items) you can retrieve it and then add into your logs. Like this:

```
var correlationId = context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("CorrelationId")? 
                      context.Request.Headers["CorrelationId"].First()
                    : null;
```

If you don't want to push correlationId property manually you can use global properties of a logger. For Serilog you can use PushProperty method on already existing middleware:

```
LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", correlationIdValue);
```